# pandas: data types between column and its element differs

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime, dtype

I've loaded a CSV file into a Panda data frame and cleaned the data elements. For a specific column the envisaged data type is datetime.time. All elements in that column are shown as data type date time.time but the column itself is shown as type object which makes the processing afterwards difficult. I've even added another line to convert the elements to time type:

What do I need to do to get the column as type datetime.time?

```
Here is the data:

0       00:52:08
1       01:24:02
2       00:45:06
3       00:59:38
4       00:53:12
          ...   
1242    00:41:07
1243    00:58:28
1244    00:39:57
1245    01:13:14
1246    00:56:02
Name: Zeit, Length: 1247, dtype: object

And the types I get:

0       <class 'datetime.time'>
1       <class 'datetime.time'>
2       <class 'datetime.time'>
3       <class 'datetime.time'>
4       <class 'datetime.time'>
                 ...           
1242    <class 'datetime.time'>
1243    <class 'datetime.time'>
1244    <class 'datetime.time'>
1245    <class 'datetime.time'>
1246    <class 'datetime.time'>
Name: Zeit, Length: 1247, dtype: object
```

Here is the code including the "data cleaning" function

```
def convertRunTime(timeString) : #convert the time string into a datetime object and set 0 values in case of missing values
    try :
        format="%H:%M:%S"
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(timeString,format).time()
    except ValueError:
        try :
            pos=timeString.rfind(',')
            if(pos !=0 ) :
                return datetime.datetime.strptime(timeString[0:pos],format).time()
        except ValueError as err:
            print("Error converting run time ", timeString, " ", err)
            return datetime.time()

try:
    paceData['Zeit'] = paceData['Zeit'].map(convertRunTime)
    paceData['Zeit'] = pd.to_datetime(paceData['Zeit'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time
except ValueError as err:
    print("invalid time: ", err)
```

Comment: Output depends on logic (function) *and* data.  Please post your source data if you want an answer

Comment: what does dtypes give you?

Comment: Data and dtypes inserted now. Thank you!

Comment: it's expected **dtype** is object as `datetime.time` is not a native datatype, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/getting_started/basics.html#basics-dtypes

Comment: Thanks a lot @RobRaymond. It's clear now :-)